# Marginal probability density function for each $X_j$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, density-function

Let $X_1, \ldots , X_n$ i.i.d with $X_1\sim \text{Exp}(5\theta)$. For the statistical distribution of $\theta$ the a priori belief is described by $\text{Gamma}(\alpha,1)$, where $a$ a positive parameter.

1. Find the Marginal probability density function for each $X_j$.
2. Find the estimator for $\theta$ according to Bayes considering the square loss function.

For the first question we have to calculate the integral $$f_{X_j}(x_j)=\int_0^{\infty}f_{x_1\ldots x_n}(x_1, \ldots , x_n)\, dx_1, \ldots dx_{j-1} dx_{j+1}\ldots dx_n$$ or not?

So first we have to find the function $f_{x_1\ldots x_n}(x_1, \ldots , x_n)$.

Knowing that $X_1\sim \text{Exp}(5\theta)$ does the following hold?
$$f_{X_1\mid \Theta }(x\mid \theta)=\begin{cases}5\theta e^{-5\theta x_1} & \text{ for } x> 0 \\ 0 & \text{ for } x\leq 0\end{cases}$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118736/discussion-on-question-by-mary-star-marginal-probability-density-function-for-ea).

Answer (score 0):

The MSE community suggests me to avoid long conversation in comments.

For the fisrt question below is a integral using gamma function,
$$f_X(x)=\int_0^{+\infty}\prod_{i=1}^{n}(5\theta e^{-5\theta x_i}) \frac{1} {\Gamma(\alpha)}\theta^{\alpha-1}e^{-\theta}d\theta=\frac{5^n}{\Gamma{(\alpha)}}(1+5\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i)\Gamma(n+\alpha)$$
Foe the second, Bayes estimation will be
$$\theta=\mathbb{E}[\theta|X=x]=\frac{\int\theta f_\Theta(\theta)f_{X|\Theta}(x|\theta)d\theta}{\int f_\Theta(\theta)f_{X|\Theta}(x|\theta)d\theta}=(1+5\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i)(n+1+\alpha)$$

For the UMVUE，a common method is to use Lehmann–Scheffé theorem, to check the distribution family is complete and from the fisrt question $S=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ is a complete statistic. And find a statistic $\Theta$ with $\theta$ expectation and then calculate $\mathbb{E}(\Theta|X)$

Comment: Ahh so $f_{X\mid \Theta}$ is the product of all $f_{X_j\mid \Theta}$, right?

Comment: Yes, by independence.

Comment: Aok so we have that $$f_X(x)=\frac{5^n}{\Gamma (\alpha)}\int_0^{\infty}\theta^{n+\alpha+1}e^{-\left (1+5\sum x_i\right )\theta}\, d\theta$$ your result with Gamma function is it a properties of those functions?

Comment: It is $\Gamma (z)=\int_0^{\infty}x^{z-1}e^{-x}\, dx$ but in our case the power of the exponential function is not the same as the base of the polynomial.

Comment: So we have to do the following: $$\int_0^{\infty}\theta^{n+\alpha+1}e^{-\left (1+5\sum x_i\right )\theta}\, d\theta=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\left (1+5\sum x_i\right )^{n+\alpha+1}}{\left (1+5\sum x_i\right )^{n+\alpha+1}}\theta^{n+\alpha+1}e^{-\left (1+5\sum x_i\right )\theta}\, d\theta=\frac{1}{\left (1+5\sum x_i\right )^{n+\alpha+1}}\int_0^{\infty}\left [\left (1+5\sum x_i\right )\theta\right ]^{n+\alpha+1}\theta^{n+\alpha+1}e^{-\left (1+5\sum x_i\right )\theta}\, d\theta$$ right?